# CheckBox no Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou tentando criar uma Lista, que mostra os ingredientes necessários, e ao lado deles, uma CheckBox, simulando o que o usuário pegou ou não. Tentei Checkbox, CheckboxListTile, mas não faço ideia do que fazer. O checkbox somente precisa mudar de 'não checado' para 'checado'. Estou usando um StatefulWidget.

```
 class CheckboxClasse extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _CheckboxState createState() => _CheckboxState();
    }

    class _CheckboxState extends State<CheckboxClasse> {
      bool isCheck = false;
      List<Meal> meal;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListTile(
            title: new Row(children: <Widget>[
          new CheckboxListTile(
            value: isCheck,
            onChanged: (bool newValue) {
              setState(() {
                isCheck = newValue;
              });
            },
            activeColor: Colors.pink,
            checkColor: Colors.green,
          ),
        ]));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Se entendi bem seu código tem pontos a serem pensados... O `ListTile()` foi criado para apresentar informações de um modo organizado e bonito e funciona bem. O `CheckboxListTile()` é uma variação do `ListTile`... entendendo isso, qual motivo te fez colocar um `CheckboxListTile` dentro de uma `Row` que por sua vez está dentro de um `ListTile`?... Tentou usar apenas o `CheckboxListTile` e preencher os atributos que ele possui?

Comment: Não tentei, mas vou tentar agora! É que eu estou tentando mostrar uma lista, que está em outra classe, mas não consigo chamar o 'meal.ingredientes', que é a lista que vai ter o checkbox do ladinho, tentei usar um '.ToList()' e '.ToString()', mas não faço ideia do que fazer...

Comment: Coloquei como resposta um exemplo de utilização de uma lista com um `check` e pode rodar ela no dartpad mesmo... diante do que você apresentou de código foi o que deu pra orientar... caso não seja suficiente, edite sua pergunta e coloque o código completo da aplicação e assim será possível analisar o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo que estude a documentação dos componentes [ListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) e [CheckboxListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html) para entender melhor como funcionam. Lembre-se que eles foram criados apenas para facilitar a implementação de componentes úteis que são utilizados em inúmeros apps. No seu caso nota-se que não realizou os testes básicos de cada um isoladamente explorando suas propriedades.

Não existe a necessidade de inserir um `CheckboxListTile` dentro de um `ListTile`. O `CheckboxListTile` já foi criado visando mostrar o check, ele nasceu pra isso. Neste seu exemplo tudo que precisa é dele.

Montei um exemplo que poderá ser analisado por você com intuito de entender seu funcionamento.

### Exemplo

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final itens = <Map>[
    {"nome": "Arroz", "check": false},
    {"nome": "Feijão", "check": false},
    {"nome": "Macarrão", "check": false},
    {"nome": "Leite", "check": false},
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: itens.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
        return CheckboxListTile(
          title: Text(itens[index]["nome"]),
          subtitle: Text(
            "Este item ${itens[index]["check"] ? "" : "não"} está selecionado",
          ),
          value: itens[index]["check"],
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              itens[index]["check"] = newValue;
            });
            print(
              "Mudou check da palavra ${itens[index]["nome"]} para: $newValue",
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Este código pode ser copiado e colado no [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/). Recomendo que utilize muito ele para criar exemplos e entender os comportamentos de cada componente que já te é oferecido pronto para utilizar.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui usar o CheckBox segundo suas dicas, agradeço muito. Agora só preciso fazer a chamada da classe no Widget que eu quero, porém da erro no Card(). Será que é por causa de um ser Stateful e a classe que eu vou fazer chamada do Checkbox é Stateless?

Segue o código.

//imports

class MealDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final meal = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Meal;

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(meal.title),
    ),
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 300,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Image.network(
              meal.imageUrl,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
            child: Text('Ingredientes', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title),
          ),
          Container(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            height: 400,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: meal.ingredientes.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return Card(
                CheckboxClasse(),  //classe Stateful
                child: Text(meal.ingredientes[index], 
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                color: Colors.red[50],
                elevation: 5,
               );
            }),
          ),

            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

class CheckboxClasse extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckboxState createState() => _CheckboxState();
}

class _CheckboxState extends State<CheckboxClasse> {
  // void changeBox(bool valorzim) => setState(() => changedBox = valorzim);
  final List<Meal> meal = new List<Meal>();
  bool changedBox = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CheckboxListTile(
      value: changedBox,
      onChanged: (bool valCheck) {
        setState(() {
          changedBox = valCheck;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Se o problema da pergunta original foi resolvido sinalize como resposta válida. Como surgiu outra coisa que não é o principal perguntado abra uma nova pergunta. É importante ressaltar também que o Stack segue um padrão de foco em problemas específicos e não é recomendado que sejam feitas réplicas e tréplicas em um post, caso queira fazer algum comentário utilize os próprios comentário da pergunta ou da resposta. Procure sempre seguir as regras da plataforma para não receber votos negativos.